# Get current field value on Doctrine MongoDB ODM Update query

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, query-builder, odm

I ma trying to update several fields but to do that I need to update the current field value by applying a php function on it (like strtolower). But I don't know how to get the current value, i just can set a new one :

```
$qb->update()
   ->multiple(true)
   ->field($fieldName)->set($action($value))
```

How can I get the $value which is the current field value ?

Comment: You have to fetch all documents and modify field in loop.

Comment: Yes this is what i've done, thank you !